# How to execute the python program from a python program

Tags: python, file, os.system, python-os

I am explaining my questions in steps below:

First.py ( This as only one print statement : Print(‘Hi’)
FirstCopy.py( This is copied from FirstCopy.py : so has same statement Print(‘Hi’)

1. Reading a file First.py
2. Writing it to a new file FirstCopy.py
3. Now executing the file through os.system(Python First.py) . I am getting output ‘Hi’.
4. Now executing the file through os.system(Python FiratCopy.py). I am not getting any output and there are no errors also.
5. When I tried printing the return value of os.system() for both. Am getting it as 0. Please

Regards,
Shri Karthigeyan

Please find the code below,

```
Import os 

f = ‘c:\First.py’
f1 = open(‘c:\FirstCopy.py’,w)

with open(f,‘r’) as myfile:
    for l in myfile:
        f1.write(l)

Final = os.system(‘Python c:\First.py‘)
Ffinal = os.system(‘Python c:\FirstCopy.py‘)
Print(Final)
Print(Ffinal)
```

Output:

Hi
0
0

Comment: format ur question, its confusing!

Comment: What is in FirstCopy.py?

Comment: Olivier Samson : In Both First.py & FirstCopy.py i am getting name from the user through input() and printing the name.

Comment: Sorry Shri, your question is not understandable. Please have a look at the question's requirements of stack overflow so we may help you out.

Comment: @Shrikarthigeyan.Nshri  it looks like the copy file pointer(f1)is not closed before executing the file using os.system. Hence it is not getting executed. Try closing the file. Also please format the question for better understanding of the problem.

Comment: @heretolearn Thanks a lot closing the pointer solved the issue....